# Control Panel Empty on Windows Server 2008 R2 DataCenter

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I am a local admin on a Windows Server 2008 R2 DataCenter machine, but when I remote into the server and open the Control Panel, almost all of the items are gone or missing.

Could there be a security setting somewhere that is preventing these from displaying?

[image: Empty Control Panel]

If I click on Control Panel Home, here's a [screenshot of my only options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmxYi.png): Date and Time, Fonts, Keyboard, and Mouse.

Comment: What does the output from gpresult /h gpresult.html show for the control panel settings?

Comment: @GregAskew, thanks.  After running the Group Policy Results, I see that ["Show only specified Control Panel items" has been enabled](http://i.imgur.com/EEUcj8q.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As GregAskew pointed out, I was able to survey the Group Policy Settings by going to the command prompt and using [gpresult](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160.aspx):

```
gpresult /h gpresult.html
```

This helped identify the fact that a group policy was in effect to "[Show only specified Control Panel items](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940227.aspx)":

[image: gp result]

If you have permissions, you can locally override this by [enabling this setting on the Local Group Policy Editor](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hide-show-add-remove-control-panel-applets)

First, run **`gpedit.msc`** from the command prompt, then navigate to:
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel

[image: Group Policy Editor]

Now you can add in Control Panel Items you want to see.

You can generate a list of Control Panel Items by going to `C:\Windows\System32` and searching for "*.cpl"